# CoreMediaIO camera driver not detected until restart of application

Tags: google-chrome, camera, driver

We have created a CoreMediaIO plug-in sample camera driver .The installation works and the camera is installed.An application like AVRecorder or FaceTime is able to detect our camera driver if its opened AFTER the installation of the camera driver. However, if the application is already opened and then the camera is installed, the list of devices does not refresh and the application does not detect our camera driver. The only way it will detect is if we close the application and start it again. (this does not seem to be the case when i connect a new USB camera. Open applications auto detects newly connected usb camera.)

What is the missing event that our camera driver needs to send to announce its installation or arrival? We basically need the camera to be detected without having to close the application and reopen.
Example if we have a chrome browser open and our camera driver was installed, it should see this new camera when i use the getUserMedia(). We have seen that a USB camera is able to show up this way.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: It is written in c++. it is mostly same as the sample in https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/CoreMediaIO/Introduction/Intro.html